# jquery and textarea

Tags: php, jquery, textarea

i have this jQuery code:

```
$("#text_a").html('<textarea name = "text">".$text_user."</textarea>');
```

And if I put in textarea text with new line i get this error:

```
unterminated string literal
```

I get an error with this text:

```
First line...
Second line ...
```

Comment: Is this the actual JavaScript code that runs on the browser? Or is it some PHP source code?

Comment: Are you setting the value of $text_user by php?

Comment: @Anzeo - It *is* PHP `.$text_user.` is concatenating the string with the PHP variable, this isn't the rendered version.

Comment: @lolalola, I've just retagged the question for you. Whatever, try to post *real code* in the future. The issue is often in the exact syntax used.

Comment: @Álvaro - He's posting the real code, I don't understand the confusion here?

Comment: @Nick Craver, she says it's PHP but it's not valid PHP at all.

Comment: @Álvaro - Sure it is, it's just a string concatenation in some PHP output.

Comment: @Nick Craver, look again. If you surround it with <?php ... ?> tags it'll trigger a warning. If you run it as is, it'll never use $text_user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is actually a PHP question, I normally use [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) to generate JavaScript strings. E.g.:

```
// Prints: var myString = "Hello\nWorld";
var myString = <?php echo json_encode("Hello\nWorld"); ?>;
```

Back into JavaScript, you probably want to avoid HTML injection and XSS attacks:

```
var myTextarea = $('<textarea name="text"></textarea>').text(<?php echo json_encode($text_user); ?>);
$("#text_a").html(myTextarea);
```

## Addendum

A little test case that illustrates the need of proper escaping:

```
<?php

$text_user = '</textarea><a href="http://www.google.com">Google></a><textarea>';

?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
jQuery(function($){
    // Proper escaping
    var myTextarea = $('<textarea name="text"></textarea>').text(<?php echo json_encode($text_user); ?>);
    $("#text_a").html(myTextarea);

    // HTML injection
    $("#text_b").html('<textarea name="text">' + <?php echo json_encode($text_user); ?> + '</textarea>');
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="text_a"></div>
<div id="text_b"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.html()` gets the *inner* HTML of an element, so this won't have the same effect.

Comment: @Nick Craver, I've just fixed the JavaScript part. It should work as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing PHP with javascript. Could be something like:

```
var text_user = "<?= nl2br(htmlentities($text_user)) ?>";
$("#text_a").html('<textarea name = "text">'+text_user+'</textarea>');
```

Concatenation operator in ecmascript is "+", not "." like in PHP.

Comment: What the OP posted *was* PHP, and what you're posting would have the exact same error of an unterminated string literal.

Comment: @nick: Thanks, he should not only escape "\n" as well quotes. I think his code would not work either as javascript or PHP, and the question is tagged jequery/textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have line breaks in the middle of a string, you either need:

```
$("#text_a").html('<textarea name="text">First line...\
Second line ...</textarea>');
```

Or better in my opinion, escape your newlines, like this:

```
$("#text_a").html('<textarea name="text">First line...\nSecond line ...</textarea>');
```

[There are a few encoding options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines), for example:

```
$("#text_a").html('<textarea name = "text">".json_encode($text_user)."</textarea>');
```

Comment: But how escape all new lines in php string?

Comment: @lolalola - Like this: `$("#text_a").html('<textarea name = "text">".json_encode($text_user)."</textarea>');` See this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines